# Issue with Rails gems and bundle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a new Rails 5.0.2 project using ruby "~> 2.4.2".

I can start the server and work on the project locally just fine.

However, I just tried to generate a model and ran into some odd behavior that I don't understand.

```
rails g model Sensor
/Users/brianrhea/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:88:in `block in materialize': Could not find nokogiri-1.8.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

So, I ran `bundle` and confirmed that `Using nokogiri 1.8.2` was already installed.

So, I ran `gem install nokigiri`, it installed fine, then I did this:

```
rails g model Sensor
/Users/brianrhea/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:88:in `block in materialize': Could not find pg-0.21.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

Ok, now it's complaining about `pg` so I did `gem install pg-0.21.0`

Then ran `rails g model Sensor` and it worked.

Any idea what's going on here? Have I somehow confused this project as to where to look for its gems?

Edit:

For additional context, when I run `rails new project_name` I get the following error:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:319:in `to_specs': Could not find 'rails-dom-testing' (~> 2.0) - did find: [rails-dom-testing-1.0.9,rails-dom-testing-1.0.7] (Gem::LoadError)
```

Comment: Do you get a different result when you run in the context of a particular bundle?  i.e.:  `bundle exec rails g model Sensor`

Comment: Hmmm, possibly. But I can't test that now that I've "fixed" this problem with this project. I'll see if I can recreate in another and give this a shot.

Comment: Given that "hand installing" gems fixed the problem, it's almost certain that it's an issue of having other gems installed on your system that are getting used before the ones in your rails application.  You can sort of get away with this, until you can't.  :)  Best to be in the habit of running the bundle exec version of all of the rails commands, as this will minimize surprise.  (And while this seems on the surface to be an annoyance, it's rather the whole purpose of bundler!)

Comment: Got it! That makes sense ... to minimize the "annoyance" of running `bundle exec rails ...` is there a way to tell Rails/bundle, "Hey, whenever I run a `rails` command in this repo, I always mean `bundle exec rails...`?

Answer (score 0):

Set an alias for bundle exec in your computer’s .bash_profile or .zshrc for zsh.

```
alias be='bundle exec' to .bash_profile or .zshrc
```

Then running the code would be something like this:

```
be rails g model
```

or look into binstubs: https://bundler.io/v1.7/bundle_binstubs.html